# Exact Target integration with Ruby examples?

Tags: ruby, soap4r

Anyone used Ruby or Rails to integrate with Exact Target's API or have a good example of using WSSE with SOAP4r?

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/sbraford/rbet

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released an open source Ruby on Rails web service library that ties into the ExactTarget SOAP API. It covers most of the major objects and methods, with less used usages being rolled out in subsequent releases.

I hope this helps:
http://bit.ly/a6uOZy